# TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tupleをうまく解消できない

Tags: python, 機械学習, pytorch

pytorchで学習したモデルの推論を行いたいです。
モデルは、入力は2つ、出力は１つです。
そのため、入力を２つ入れて推論を行おうとしましたが、うまく動きません。
どうすればうまく動かせるのですか？

```
x_1 = np.arange(0.49, 1+2*10**-3, 2*10**-3)   
x_2 = [0.8 for i in range(len(x_1))]

                     
x_test1 = torch.from_numpy(x_1.astype(np.float32)).float().to(device)       # xをテンソルに変換
x_test2 = torch.from_numpy(np.array(x_2).astype(np.float32)).float().to(device)       # xをテンソルに変換

X_test = torch.stack([x_test1, x_test2], 1).to(device)

net.eval()
a = []
for i in enumerate(X_test):
    outputs = net(i)
    a.append(outputs)
```

エラー

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-78f9e90abbc3> in <module>()
      9 
     10 for i in enumerate(X_test):
---> 11     outputs = net(i)
     12     a.append(outputs)
     13 

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1846     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
   1847         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1848     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1849 
   1850 

TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

forループにおける[enumerate関数の説明](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)では
インデックスとオブジェクトのtupleを返すようになっています。

おそらくnet関数の引数はTensorである必要があると思うので、
単にTensorが欲しいのであればX_TestがTensorを要素に持つリストであることを前提に以下のように書き換えてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```python
for x in X_test:
    outputs = net(x)
    a.append(outputs)
```